# Change the size of background style

Tags: javascript, css, navbar

I have a nave bar that I change style and there is a slider at the bottom of it
but I have a background , But I want to change the size of image when slider is active
this is a navbar . nav bar is a a boot strap that is fix on top

and the slider is an Image and a table

````html
<section class="home-slider js-fullheight owl-carousel bg-white">
  <div class="slider-item js-fullheight">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
      <div class="row d-md-flex no-gutters slider-text js-fullheight align-items-center justify-content-end" data-scrollax-parent="true">
        <div class="one-third order-md-last img js-fullheight" style="background-image:url(images/bg_3.jpg); ">
          <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-forth d-flex js-fullheight align-items-center ftco-animate" data-scrollax=" properties: { translateY: '70%' }">
          <div class="text mt-md-5">
            <h1 class="mb-4">Kurumsal yemek <!--<br> Delicious Foods--></h1>
            <p>A small river named Duden flows . It is a paradisematic country.</p>
            <!---- Order-->
            <div class="booking">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center">

                  <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <div class="booking-form">
                      <form>
                        <div class="control-group">
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required" />


                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
</section>
```I find this style but it does not change the size of back graound

          .owl-carousel.home-slider .slider-item {
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            height: 650px;
            margin-top: 100px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 0;
        }
````

Comment: please mention what ui kit you are using, bootstrap or any other?

Comment: bootstrap, and I can not find the style of it , it is a template and I change the margin of nav bar , so it comes a little button, so now I had to change the size of image of back ground that can show it smaller than and becomes a little toper

Comment: @MohamedRaza I add the style

Comment: batter to use bootstrap class instead of custom class

Comment: @MohamedRaza if I want too user datepicker for this form how can I change it , would you help me ?

Comment: please make a new question for it

Comment: @MohamedRaza sorry I made for it , I think you asked to it . I will appreciate you if look at that question too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77958195/change-the-size-of-background-style?noredirect=1#comment137479344_77958195

Comment: i am not ale to see the question on that link

Comment: @MohamedRaza
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77982533/how-can-i-use-date-picker-in-my-form-in-bootstarp